# How do Toggle using Zustand

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I have created the following store using Zustand:

```
import create from "zustand"

const useStore = create((set) => ({
  show: false,
  toggleShow: () => set((state) => ({ show: !state.show })),
}))
```

I assumed that this would be the correct way to toggle the value of `show`.  However, typescript is not happy -- it has a red squiggly line underneath the `show` in `!state.show` with the following error message:

```
Property 'show' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
any
```

Any idea why I am getting that error message and how I can properly set up a toggle function using Zustand?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you sort this out? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Typescript doesn't know what you state should look like, so it assumes that the state is a plain object.

To solve this, you can define a type for your store. Then, you can pass that type to the `create` function as a generic:

```
type MyStore = {
    show: boolean;
    toggleShow: () => void;
};

// note the "<MyStore>" next to create
const useStore = create<MyStore>((set) => ({
    show: false,
    toggleShow: () => set((state) => ({ show: !state.show})),
}))
```

This makes typescript aware of which properties to expect to be in your store. It will no longer throw an error for the `!state.show` part, and it will be offering meaningful autocomplete whenever you use the store.